# How can i make a sum for rows total value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a nested gridview:

```
<gridview id="gvParent" runat="server" >
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label Id="name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>' />

        <gridview id="gvChild" runat="server" >
          <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <input type="text" id="Val1'<%# Eval("Identifiant")%>'" value='<%# Eval("Val1">' onchange=  "CalculateSumRow(Val2'<%# Eval("Identifiant")%>');"/>

           </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

        <gridview id="gvChild" runat="server" >
          <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
       <input type="text" id="Val2'<%# Eval("Identifiant")%>'" value='<%# Eval("Val2")%>' onchange="CalculateSumRow(Val2'<%# Eval("Identifiant")%>');"/>

           </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>



         <asp:TemplateField>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <input type="text" id="TotalRealise<%# Eval("Identifiant")%>'" value='<%# Eval       ("TotalRealise")%>'/>

            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>


      </Columns>

    </gridview>

    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
```

In javascript   function CalculateSumRow I make sum of val1 and val 2 per row in field TotalRealise and I need a total of fields TotalRealise.I try to make a javascript function  that I called from CalculateSumRow .I try to parse row by row first grid , then second grid and I want to get all totalrealise fields and make a sum with this but I receive errors when I search the second grid.I want to make that calculation from javascript.

```
 function CalculateSumRow (identifiant)
 {
   ......
  CalculateTotal();
 }

 function CalculateTotal()
 {
   var grdPar=document.getdocumentById('<%= gvParent%>');

   for(row=1;row<grdPar.rows.length;row++)
   {

      var grdChild=document.getdocumentById('<%= gvChild%>');

      for(rowC=1;row<grdChild.rows.length;rowC++)
       {
         alert(grdChild.rows[rowc].cell[3].value);
       }

    }
   }
```

Can somebody help me make this sum ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable using jQuery, try this:

```
$(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $("input[id^="TotalRealise"]").each(function(){
    sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Call the below function onchange event of input value:

```
function CalculateTotalRealise()
{
 var sum = 0;
  $("input[id^="TotalRealise"]").each(function(){
    sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
 return sum;
}
```

This will give you sum of TotalRealise fields.

Comment: But my fields has an identifiant at the end , like TotalRealise1,TotalRealise2,TotalRealise3.Can I get input with id start with TotalRealise ?

Comment: input[id^="TotalRealise"] will get all inputs whose id start with TotalRealise

Comment: Thanks,works fine when i load the form.But if somebody modify "val.." field I recalculate the row value .How can I call this function after each recalculation from the line?

Answer (score 0):

Its better to do this in your OnRowDataBound event of the grid

```
double totalSum = 0;
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int columnValue = 0;

    // get the value from column index 0, can be any other index where you have your value
    int.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[0].Text, out columnValue);

    if (columnValue > 0)
    {
        totalSum = totalSum + columnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want it in javascript ?